# Placing the legend outside the plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to position the legend outside the drawing box. I do not find a clean way to do this.  The main problem is having everything fit on the file saved. The only thing I have been able to figure out is this code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import matplotlib
# matplotlib.use('pdf')

from matplotlib.pyplot import *
subplot(111)
plot([1,2,3], label="test1")
l=legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2,borderaxespad=0)
tight_layout(rect=(0,0,0.8,1))
savefig('test.pdf')
```

There are a couple of caveats:

1. The tight_layout seems to be incompatible with `matplotlib.use('pdf')`
2. The 0.8 in the `tight_layout` has been found by trials and errors. If I replace `label="test"` by `label="this is a very very long test"`, the legend will once again get out of the border of the file. I would like that to be adjusted automatically. I have not been able to retrieve the size of the legend. `l.get_frame().get_width()` seems to always return 1.0.
3. The `tight_layout` changes the size of the plot. What I would like to achieve is: specify the size of the plot in cm (or in inches). Placing the legend outside the plot. Having a file with the correct size in order that everything fits in, including the legend; without having to resort to trial and errors.

Comment: The `savefig` command has an option `bbox_inches='tight'`that do mostly what I want; at least for a static saved figure. The `show()` command has no such option, so I cannot consider this to be really solved. Moreover I still wonder how to retrieve the size of the legend (in case we want to make fine placement based on computations).

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700614/how-to-put-the-legend-out-of-the-plot) question by [Joe Kington](https://stackoverflow.com/users/325565/joe-kington).
The answer describes most of the options you can play around with regarding placement of legends.